# javascript alert block page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, alert

My client wishes to show an alert when entering a web page.

However, an alert blocks further loading of the page until "Ok" is clicked, and the page needs to load in the background while the alert is displayed.

One solution would be to use a custom alert using HTML and CSS, but this is not answering the client's needs.

Is there a solution using 'core javascript' or jQuery to allow the page to load while the alert is displayed?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just wait that the page is loaded to display the alert?

Comment: I understand... So you could make a custom alert that looks exactly the same as the native alert :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should run it through a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('hello world'); }, 1);
```

This is shown here:
[Is there a JavaScript alert that doesn't pause the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303720/is-there-a-javascript-alert-that-doesnt-pause-the-script)

Comment: This is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/g33Et/   Javascript is a single thread language

Comment: Seems great then, but could you provide a link to see it working?

Comment: @FunKy  Your fiddle doesn't show any multi threading, it only show that you alert after few ms. This as nothing to do with the question. See my jsfiddle, this is how we should expect multi threading to work: when alert() display, console.log() should still works, which is obviously not the case

Comment: @roasted That's what he wanted. He wanted an alert to show up, and in the meanwhile the rest of the page to load. If you notice you can tell you see the text before clicking the ok. Check this to see the difference:
http://jsfiddle.net/xfunky/WcLS6/2/

Comment: @DipeshParmar  do you see what i see in your jsfiddle? When alert is displaying, UI is blocked!  Just use the 'run' button and you should understand what i'm talking about

Comment: @roasted i am sorry but i can see site is loading in back ground...may be i am using Firefox that's why i am seeing overlay. But as of now this did the trick..

Comment: @DipeshParmar  That's true, using FF the alert is not blocking! Well, this is quite new for me! Seems like FF implement some kind of web workers, really interesting!  Thx guys!  Of course, this is not cross browser.

Comment: @roasted Works on chrome for me. Just have to check for IE compatablity

Comment: @FunKy  in chrome (win7) and IE the iframe is not loaded. The request is done of course because the delay of the timeout but the UI is not updated until the alert dialog is closed. Could you confirm it on your side?

Comment: @roasted I'm running linux, so no IE, but the Chrome works just like the Firefox.

Comment: @roasted I just now understood what you said about the iframe, SORRY!! It doesn't load for me either, the request is sent but nothing loads. Very odd. - Screenshot : http://oi42.tinypic.com/2qau4k7.jpg

Comment: Actually `alert` is executed after the page has been parsed: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24mnG/2/).

Comment: This is an interresting article from John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: this obviously only works if the other part of the script needs less than 1ms to execute. the alert is still blocking as soon as it is called.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

see @FunKy's answer for a workaround in Firefox.  (really interesting!)

---

Simple answer is no, it's not possible!

Reason is native `alert()` dialog is UI blocking and javascript is a single thread language.

You have to use a customized dialog message.

But, if some ajax request are done just before blocking UI, when `alert()` dialog is closed, the ajax response will/should be available. So, you still can make some ajax request just before showing alert.

Comment: @FunKy No, i cannot see how this could work. Webworkers could be a solution but its not really still implemented

Comment: It works, however I haven't heard of Web Workers until now. Seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom dialog box instead of an alert box (which block page load). For exemple, [Jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is easy to use (but there are many plugins which do exactly the same thing).