# Javascript "load" event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, domcontentloaded

I want to display an alert after the button is displayed i.e., after the page is loaded.

```
<input type='button' id='lognBtn' value='btn' />
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){ alert(20); });
</script>
```

Using this code, alert is displayed before page load itself. I tried `DOMContentLoaded` too. Please help.

Comment: **Note: DOMContentLoaded event triggers on document when DOM is ready. We can apply JavaScript to elements at this stage.
All scripts are executed except those that are external with async or defer** and over here you were calling `alert` which is async

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected ... it is just that the alert is a blocking event to the browser and you have to click on it to continue. You can see from the example bellow that the alert shows the button value although the button is **not** "shown" per-se:

```html
<input type="button" id="loginBtn" value="Login" />
<script>
    addEventListener("load", function(){ 
    alert(document.getElementById('loginBtn').value) 
    });
</script>
```

You can switch to event handler on the button or use setTimeout [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913596/javascript-alert-block-page-loads)

Answer (score 1):

You can  use  setTimeout() method  to  create  a delay to  call  alert after  page loads

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
 if(document.getElementById("demo")){
   setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="demo"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as swaping the order of `<script>` and `<input/>` in your HTML:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
        alert(20); 
    });
</script>
<input type='button' id='lognBtn' value='btn' />
```

Generally, I would recommend using `DOMContentLoaded` for such things anyway. For more information on this event, [see the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: I tried it too, same result. Alert appears before the button gets displayed

Comment: Still the same. Does this work for you? My requirement is to view the button in the page before alert is displayed

Comment: In that case, I don't believe what you're requiring is possible. If the script is declared after the button, then it will be run after the button has been rendered.

Comment: As @Narendrasingh Sisodia pointed out in the comments, this might not be possible since alert is async

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. You are using `load` so the browser will display it as soon as the page loads. Simply change it to `click` like so and you will get the alert after you click on the button, therefore giving you some control over when the alert should appear and giving time for the button to render before the alert.

```html
<input type='button' id='lognBtn' value='btn' />
 <script>
  window.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert(20); }); //change here
 </script>
```

Comment: My requirement is to view the button in the page before alert is displayed without any click.

Comment: So you want to render the button first then the alert will pop up?

Comment: Yes, that's the requirement

Comment: Okay hold on, I will edit it. I misunderstood your requirement

Comment: As @Narendrasingh Sisodia pointed out in the comments, this might not be possible since alert is async

Comment: That is true. Which is why I suggested you to use `click` since then you will have some control over when the alert pops up, if at all you want it to pop up

Comment: @SamiKh In JSBin however, I see that if you swap the position of the `script` and `button` then it renders the button first and the alert immediately pops up. Check it https://jsbin.com/dazedasimo/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks. And as @Akrion mentioned, the current code works as expected too

Comment: @SamiKh Great! Could you accept the most suitable answer and mark the question as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.onload` event. Actually, the alert showing after DOM load but you can not detect the difference after button display and then the alert comes out. You can use `setTimeout` for 1 second.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ alert(20)},1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type='button' id='lognBtn' value='helloBtn'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is wrong! why negative vote here? the alert will show after dom loaded.