# `while` loop with `prompt` is never showing any `console.log`

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I was just trying to check if my console gets connected to my code, and previosly it did for the same program, but now it’s not even loading the basic HTML page which contains just the heading, and it’s not showing anything in the console. Why is it behaving like this?

[image: Screenshot showing a prompt dialog box, but no console output and the HTML page not loaded.]

```js
var todos = [ "whats up dude!!" ];
var input = prompt("what would you like to do?");

while (input !== "quit") {
  if (input === "list") {
    todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
      console.log(i + ": " + todo);
    });
  }
  else if (input === "new") {
    var newTodo = prompt("what do you want?");
    
    todos.push(newTodo);
  }
  else if (input === "delete") {
    var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
    
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Todo Removed");
  }

  input = prompt("what would you like to do?");
}

console.log("You have Quit!!");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>one more try</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tryy.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>its the last resort</h1>
  <h4>hope i win this!!</h4>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Going off the code and screenshot, you are at the prompt and there were no statements logging to the console before the prompt.  What happens after you hit ok?

Comment: It does work, but you won't see the output until you leave the loop (i.e. type quit) because the while loop is blocking everything else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript alert block page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913596/javascript-alert-block-page-loads)

Comment: @TonyAbrams i was supposed to this see that array mentioned in the code which previosly i did before it started not working anymore(or not loading)

Comment: What does the full html look like?

Comment: @MattEllen but previosly i used to get the list when i type list in that field but now its just not loading and yes it quit when i do  but then i dont understand why the console is not loading the code anymore like it did previosly

Comment: @TonyAbrams nothing its just basic code

Comment: @TonyAbrams <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>one more try</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="tryy.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>its the last resort</h1>
 <h4>hope i win this!!</h4>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @Shilly its still the same

Comment: Can you post the previous code that worked?

Comment: @slebetman its the same code

Comment: This is a weird one. Due to the while-loop, neither `DOMContentLoaded` event or `load` event, or even setTimeout() seem to work 100% of the time. So I would put my effort in replacing the prompt()/while() loop with something that does not fight us., like having the previous answer trigger the next question, so you do not need to loop at all.

Comment: @shilly how do you suggest it should if not using prompt, could you actually show me and help me out by giving the code you are talking about.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel  i do not understand you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a tight loop that never yields control of the script, or page, to anything else, you can put a small delay before each prompt with `setTimeout`:

```js
var todos=["whats up dude!!"];

function interactWithToDos()
{
  var input=prompt("what would you like to do?");
  
  if(input==="list")
  {
    todos.forEach(function(todo, i)
    {
      console.log(i +": "+ todo);
    });
  }
  else if(input==="new")
  {
    var newTodo=prompt("what do you want?");
    todos.push(newTodo);
  }
  else if(input === "delete")
  {
    var index = prompt("Enter index of todo to delete");
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("Todo Removed");
  }
  
  if(input !== "quit")
  {
    setTimeout(interactWithToDos, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("You have Quit!!");
  }
}

setTimeout(interactWithToDos, 0);
```

Comment: a delay of 0 is fine

Comment: I did not know. Updated!