# Show Chrome dialogs without freezing page

Tags: css, google-chrome, alert

I need to show a dialog box that's is like chrome's. But I want a modal alert, because js alert freeze the page.

I tried getting the css from it, but I think it's not possible.

Does anyone know how to do it? Or have the css for it?

[Chrome JS Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNgJi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript alert that doesn't pause the script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303720/is-there-a-javascript-alert-that-doesnt-pause-the-script)

Comment: Actually I just want a js alert like chrome, but without freezing it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this page. Sounds exactly like what you're trying to do. It uses the onload javascript attribute, which says "run when the document is finished loading".
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_88.html