# How to show alert in the next event loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning VueJS and created this little practice game to enhance my knowledge on Vue.

http://jsfiddle.net/mzref4o0/1/

this attack method will also determine the winner:

```
attack: function(isSpecialAttack) {
        let youHurt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      let monsterHurt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      if (isSpecialAttack) {
        youHurt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
        monsterHurt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
      }
        this.you.bloodLevel -= youHurt;
      this.monster.bloodLevel -= monsterHurt;

      this.messages.push([
        {id: this.getRandomId, turn: 'you', msg: 'PLAYER HTIS MONSTER FOR ' + monsterHurt},
        {id: this.getRandomId, turn: 'monster', msg: 'MONSTER HTIS PLAYER FOR ' + youHurt}
      ])


      if (this.you.bloodLevel <= 0 || this.monster.bloodLevel <= 0) {
        if (this.you.bloodLevel <= 0) {
          alert('you lost');
        } else {
          alert('you won');
        }
      }
    },
```

The problem is that the alert message shows up before the "attack" happens, meaning the blood bar drops & the message is added after the alert message is shown. How do I make the alert shows up only after those two things happened?

I think this problem is due to event loop... but that's all I know.

Comment: Have you tried using a promise. like wrap the funciton in a promise and then after calling it. execute the message push. or maybe try using `nextTick()`. [here's the docs on nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can't **really** work with `alert`.

`alert` method is blocking the execution of code, therefore the browser does not start to deal with the re-painting until the block is released.

A solution [was suggested in other stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303720/is-there-a-javascript-alert-that-doesnt-pause-the-script)

I highly recommend to use more modern techniques, like [vue-js modals](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).

anyway, this block of code should work :

```
    if (this.you.bloodLevel <= 0 || this.monster.bloodLevel <= 0) {
      if (this.you.bloodLevel <= 0) {
        setTimeout("alert('you lost');", 1);

      } else {
        setTimeout("alert('you won');", 1);

      }
    }
```

Comment: The code results in an error. The browser says `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'...`. It's better to pass a function to setTimeout:, like `setTimeout(() => alert('you win'), 1);`