# Javascript loads before page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am having a strange problem with my google chrome browser.
Every time I try to run a simple small javascript code and do alert box my HTML page is white and alert box pop-ups first.

So far I tried:

- Putting scrip tag `<script></script>` at the end of body tag
  `</body>`
- Using `defer`
- Using `async`
- Clearing cache of my browser and restarting it.

Keep in mind that in Mozilla, edge and other browsers I have no problems and simple solution as placing a script tag at the end near closing body tag does the trick. So it's working in every other browser just not in chrome.

I am using:

- Windows 10
- Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

(I did see similar questions posted here but didn't find an answer for fixing it as I tried all they recomended)

Comment: Check out the `load` event.  If you want to fire your dialog earlier than this, use `DOMContentLoaded` event, with a `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303720/is-there-a-javascript-alert-that-doesnt-pause-the-script

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `window.onload()` function in JavaScript

It load the JavaScript contents after the window is fully loaded.

You can put or initialize all your JavaScript inside `window.onload()`

For example;

```
window.onload() {
    // Put your JavaScript code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There. Just use the `window.onload = function() {}`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("elementToChange").innerHTML = "changed!";
}
```

```html
<div id="elementToChange">hiiiiii</div>
```