# Why the HTML DOM event doesn't affect immediately on the same DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, pure-js

I'm writing the code to change the Button element value when the click event is executing.

But Until it finishes it doesn't affect the button element value.

I attached the fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qjLmx1ck/3/) which will give you a good idea of what I'm talking about.

```
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
 alert('hi')
}
```

Even the button element innerHTML changed before alert, it doesn't affect the UI.

How can I accomplish, before the alert is executed I need to change the button text?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript alert that doesn't pause the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303720/is-there-a-javascript-alert-that-doesnt-pause-the-script)

Comment: You could listen for the button value to change, and fire the alert after the change, or am I wrong?

Comment: @D.Schaller no, that is a better idea. But What is the reason for this behavior of JS?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Javascript thread execution stops until you click the confirm button in the alert. You would say: but why? if the HTML change instruction was executed before. Well, although the Javascript code was executed, the browser still didn't make the changes in the DOM.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'thread execution' because that might confuse people - JavaScript doesn't have real threads.

Comment: Yep, Javascript execution is a single thread process, but a thread is a thread, right?

Comment: Threads, generally, are components of a process that can be managed independently by the scheduler. While what you say is technically correct mentioning it can be confusing in this context because JavaScript has no concept of or access to the underlying threads. It probably doesn't matter much - but I just would say that "the JavaScript execution pauses" or "the JavaScript engine pauses"

Answer (score 1):

Closest to threading in JS is settimeout function, this is not ok to do but here is how would it look like if you use it

```
 function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert('hi')
  },1000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a proper explanation of why it happens, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986563/2206733).

TL;DR see [Josè's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220181/2206733).

Here's how you can quickly fix this

```
setTimeout(_=>alert('hi'))
```